# Why aren't my changes to /etc/security/limits.conf having effect?

Tags: kernel, filesystem

I am trying to provide support for core dumps on my Ubuntu machine (as by default they are disabled). So I have made the following changes to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
root hard core 1000
```

After adding this line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`, I was expecting the generation of core files but `ulimit -a` shows me:

```
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
```

Why aren't the changes in `/etc/security/limits.conf` reflected in `ulimit`?

What should I do to have them taken into account?